# Create a file with the information about line position of multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, grep, scripting

I have a file with the following column:

```
GEOM_190_190  
GEOM_190_192  
GEOM_190_194  
GEOM_190_196  
...
```

Its length is around 3000 lines.

I would like to write a script that creates a file with the line where these names are written.
As far I reached I have:

```
for f in extra.csv
do
 print grep -n 'f' structure.xyz >> ex.csv
done
```

Desired output:

```
2:GEOM_190_190  
10:GEOM_190_192  
18:GEOM_190_194
```

The `structures.xyz` file where the names should be found is around 100000 lines and looks like this:

```
6  
GEOM_190_190  
C -0.8067180 0.0475439 1.5251484  
S 0.3116624 0.2691858 0.0786324  
C -1.7790900 0.0209031 -1.8054100  
S -0.5677430 -1.0588900 -0.9579280  
C 2.5277800 0.5632240 1.8126600  
S 1.2848000 1.6235700 0.9897200  
6  
GEOM_190_192  
...
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the first file that you show your `extra.csv`? if so, it sounds like what you want is `grep -Fnf extra.csv structures.xyz`

Comment: It looks like you just need `grep -n ^GEOM`.  Is there something more?

Comment: Not all of them start with GEOM, some of them have different names,  and I don't want all the GEOM's, only the ones indicated in the first file, that is why I wanted to declare the whole line as the varaible

Comment: You have one file or two files? and you want to create one more file? You want GEOM but not all GEOM?...

Answer (score 2):

Grep(1) can do what you want, try.

```
grep -Fnx -f extra.csv structure.xyz
```

Redirect the output to a file

```
grep -Fnx -f extra.csv structure.xyz > ex.csv
```

If you want to see the output and at the same time redirect to a file, use `tee`

```
grep -Fnx -f extra.csv structure.xyz | tee ex.csv
```

That should give you the result you want if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it!

```
file="extra.csv"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
grep -n "$line" structures.xyz | cut -f1 -d: >> ex.csv
done <"$file"
```

Comment: that will run grep 3k times because the file has 3k lines....

Comment: Don't do that, it'll take forever to run. Any time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach.